# c++ thread worker failure under high load

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I have been working on a idea for a system where I can have many workers that are triggered on a regular basis by a a central timer class. The part I'm concerned about here is a `TriggeredWorker` which, in a loop, uses the `mutex` & `conditionVariable` approach to wait to be told to do work. It has a method `trigger` that is called (by a different thread) that triggers work to be done. It is an abstract class that has to be subclassed for the actual `work` method to be implemented.

I have a test that shows that this mechanism works. However, as I increase the load by reducing the trigger interval, the test starts to fail. When I delay 20 microseconds between triggers, the test is 100% reliable. As I reduce down to 1 microsecond, I start to get failures in that the count of work performed reduces from 1000 (expected) to values like 986, 933, 999 etc..

My questions are: (1) what is it that is going wrong and how can I capture what is going wrong so I can report it or do something about it? And, (2) is there some better approach that I could use that would be better? I have to admit that my experience with c++ is limited to the last 3 months, although I have worked with other languages for several years.

Many thanks for reading...

Here are the key bits of code:

Triggered worker header file:

```cpp
#ifndef TIMER_TRIGGERED_WORKER_H
#define TIMER_TRIGGERED_WORKER_H

#include <thread>
#include <plog/Log.h>

class TriggeredWorker {
private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable condVar_;
    std::atomic<bool> running_{false};
    std::atomic<bool> ready_{false};

    void workLoop();
protected:
    virtual void work() {};
public:
    void start();
    void stop();
    void trigger();
};

#endif //TIMER_TRIGGERED_WORKER_H
```

Triggered worker implementation:

```cpp
#include "TriggeredWorker.h"

void TriggeredWorker::workLoop() {
    PLOGD << "workLoop started...";

    while(true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        condVar_.wait(lock, [this]{
            bool ready = this->ready_;
            bool running = this->running_;
            return ready | !running; });
        this->ready_ = false;

        if (!this->running_) {
            break;
        }

        PLOGD << "Calling work()...";
        work();

        lock.unlock();
        condVar_.notify_one();
    }

    PLOGD << "Worker thread completed.";
}

void TriggeredWorker::start() {
    PLOGD << "Worker start...";
    this->running_ = true;
    auto thread = std::thread(&TriggeredWorker::workLoop, this);
    thread.detach();
}

void TriggeredWorker::stop() {
    PLOGD << "Worker stop.";
    this->running_ = false;
}

void TriggeredWorker::trigger() {
    PLOGD << "Trigger.";
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    ready_ = true;
    lock.unlock();
    condVar_.notify_one();
}
```

and the test:

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "TriggeredWorker.h"
#include <thread>

TEST_CASE("Simple worker performs work when triggered") {
    static std::atomic<int> twt_count{0};

    class SimpleTriggeredWorker : public TriggeredWorker {
    protected:
        void work() override {
            PLOGD << "Incrementing counter.";
            twt_count.fetch_add(1);
        }
    };

    SimpleTriggeredWorker worker;

    worker.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        worker.trigger();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(20));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    CHECK(twt_count == 1000);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    worker.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when `worker.trigger()` is called twice before `workLoop` acquires the lock? You loose one of those "triggers". Smaller time gap means higher probability of test failure, because of higher probability of multiple consecutive `worker.trigger()` calls before `workLoop` wakes up. Note that there's nothing that guarantees that `workLoop` will acquire the lock after `worker.trigger()` but before another `worker.trigger()` happens, even when those calls happen one after another (i.e. not in parallel). This is governed by the OS scheduler and we have no control over it.

Anyway the core problem is that setting `ready_ = true` twice looses information. Unlike incrementing an integer twice. And so the simplest solution is to replace `bool` with `int` and do inc/dec with `== 0` checks. This solution is also known as semaphore. More advanced (potentially better, especially when you need to pass some data to the worker) approach is to use a (bounded?) thread safe queue. That depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

BTW 1: all your reads and updates, except for `stop()` function (and `start()` but this isn't really relevant), happen under the lock. I suggest you fix `stop()` to be under lock as well (since it is rarely called anyway) and turn atomics into non-atomics. There's an unnecessary overhead of atomics at the moment.

BTW 2: I suggest not using `thread.detach()`. You should store the `std::thread` object on `TriggeredWorker` and add destructor that does `stop` with `join`. These are not independent beings and so without `detach()` you make your code safer (one should never die without the other).

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, I shall try them out and report back later... Question: do you know of examples of the thread safe queue of which you talk?  That does seem like a good idea.  What I want to do is do work at set regular intervals, but if there is no time for work to be done I want to drop that particular piece of work and report some how... Maybe I need to dabble with OS level stuff and/or real time operating systems...  It's all new to me!

Comment: OK, I've done most of the things you suggested, especially the very useful BTW1 and 2.  Haven't tried the semaphore thing but I expect that will work too.  At some point, given time, I shall try out the thread safe queue idea.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @MattDaley there are many different implementations of a thread safe queue. Just google "c++ thread safe queue" and read everything you get. For example this: https://github.com/krobotis/ThreadSafeQueue/blob/master/include/ThreadSafeQueue.h It's nice that you've applied my two side notes, but the core of the answer is definitely more important.

Comment: Yes, definitely going to do that.

Comment: This is probably a really good read and it suits my use case too: https://moodycamel.com/blog/2013/a-fast-lock-free-queue-for-c++